# Error computing mean on data frame in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plyr

I have a DF created like this:

```
    Sample Concentration
1  Dp10 WT        121.36
2  Dp10 WT        129.11
3  Dp10 WT        149.46
4     Dp10         141.3
5     Dp10        129.11
6     Dp10        131.02
7  Dp16 WT             0
8  Dp16 WT         134.8
9  Dp16 WT         144.5
10    Dp16        134.33
11    Dp16        129.11
12    Dp16        160.02

A = matrix(
c("Dp10 WT", "Dp10 WT", "Dp10 WT",
  "Dp10", "Dp10", "Dp10",
  "Dp16 WT", "Dp16 WT", "Dp16 WT",
  "Dp16", "Dp16", "Dp16",
  121.36, 129.11, 149.46, 141.3, 129.11, 131.02,
  0, 134.8, 144.5, 134.33, 129.11, 160.02),
nrow=12,
ncol=2,
byrow = FALSE)

dimnames(A) = list(seq(1,12)
,c('Sample', 'Concentration')) # column names
DF=data.frame(A)
```

But computing the mean as shown below gives me the following error.

```
mm <- ddply(DF, "Sample", summarise, conc = mean(Concentration, na.rm=TRUE))

Error in attributes(out) <- attributes(col) : 
'names' attribute [12] must be the same length as the vector [3]
```

I know there are some differences with mean computing on dataframes as of R 3.0 but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Your columns are stored as factors. The following edits to your code should work

```
DF=data.frame(A,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
DF$Concentration = as.numeric(DF$Concentration)
mm <- ddply(DF, "Sample", summarise, conc = mean(Concentration, na.rm=TRUE))
```